# Proper ventilation in a tight space on a laptop

Tags: laptop, owncloud, untangle, cooling

I have a laptop in a very tight space running a network firewall (please don't complain about that). However, it sometimes turns off due to overheating.  There is about 3cm of space between its can (located on the back) and the wall. Also, there is another laptop on top of it running a cloud server. The firewall is quite an old 32bit laptop and the top one is a newer 64bit laptop. How could I solve this and stop it from overheating?

Comment: Add ventilation.

Comment: Don't stack them on top of each other like that. Also, WHY are they in this tight space? Can't you move them somewhere more reasonable? They're just laptops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my laptop doing extensive calculation
in summer, working in a room without air conditioning.

1) I solved it plugging a USB-fan into the laptop
and pointing the air current to the hottest point of the 
case.

2) If you need to stack one laptop over the other I recommend
you leave some vertical space between the two.

3) This depends on you computer, but on mine (an old MacBook Pro)
it is important to keep the screen open and distant from the keyboard
because the hottest part of the case is on the top part of the keyboard.
Air needs to flow there.

4) You may consider to buy a laptop cooling pad or external fan ([search on amazon.com](http://amzn.to/28YYonl))

Answer (score 0):

USB fan(s) will be your best option, especially if you can get them with longer USBs and without a frame (or at least one you could remove easily; giving you a chance to run the wire and place the fan however you want). **Avoid** cooling pads; they're fantastic for regular use, but if your devices are in unventilated tight quarters and they are already crashing due to overheating, the pads won't be able to relinquish that heat and recrystallize. **If** you have enough space, separate them from each other on baking cooling racks.